# how to link a each cell with different value in a column in a ssrs report to different report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have created a linked report that has 5 columns,first is of branch,second of category it solds & rest 3 shows the individual category wise sales of last three years.i am able to link branch column to another report that shows other branch activities.In the same way i want to link the different individual categories to a different reports that takes Respective branch & category as parameter to filter & present the data.

[First pic shows grouping at branch, it is linked to another report too.I have not shown that report. Now when i collapse it, the category column will have 3 different categories & all 3 year columns will have sales of that individual category over the years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7O0K.png)

[Pic 2 shows the collapsed view after clicking the (+) sign of branch column. I need to link each value in category column to another report that filters data on the basis of Branch & category column. E.g if i click on 12mobilephone than it should lead to another report that shows the vales related to 12mobilephone & that particular branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSjBq.png)

Comment: you can have a drillthrough action (go to report) and have those 2 parameters that you need.

Comment: Hi Kim,
   Thanks for reverting. I tried using drill through action but the problem is when i right click the categories column in design mode & went to its action tab it ask to go to a report but i just not only want to navigate to a random report. I need the value from the category field & its respective branch as filter to get to the new report. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a drillthrough action with parameters.
First, specify the reportname that you want to drill through.
then you can add parameters, in your case you need 2 parameters.
On the **Name** : Specify the name of the parameter from the report that you are going to drill through.
On the **Value** : Specify the fieldname that has the values that will populate your drill through report parameters (Branch & Category)

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the report that you are going to drill through has the Branch & Category parameters. So you'll only have to pass a value for the parameters during the drillthrough action.

Comment: Thanks Kim...u r a jewel..u made my day..i have finally achieved what i wanted since past so many days. looking forward to your help up ahead in  near future too..regards